# NGINX - PHP-FPM Serving Movies Seek & Connection Handle

Tags: php, nginx, posix

I'm running PHP-FPM 5.6 and Nginx 1.7.6.

**I'm serving Matroska/Mp4 movies using a PHP File.** The Code is: this one:

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function( 'shutdown' );

$request = 'movie.mp4';

header( 'X-Accel-Buffering: no' ); //avoid nginx buffering.
header( 'Content-type: video/mp4' );

if ( file_exists( $request ) )
{

    $fp = @fopen( $request, 'rb' );

    $size = filesize( $request ); // File size
    $length = $size; // Content length
    $start = 0; // Start byte
    $end = $size - 1; // End byte
    header( "Accept-Ranges: 0-$length" );
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'] ) )
    {

        $c_start = $start;
        $c_end = $end;

        list( , $range ) = explode( '=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2 );
        if ( strpos( $range, ',' ) !== false )
        {
            header( 'HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable' );
            header( "Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size" );
            exit;
        }
        if ( $range == '-' )
        {
            $c_start = $size - substr( $range, 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            $range = explode( '-', $range );
            $c_start = $range[0];
            $c_end = ( isset( $range[1] ) && is_numeric( $range[1] ) ) ? $range[1] : $size;
        }
        $c_end = ( $c_end > $end ) ? $end : $c_end;
        if ( $c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size )
        {
            header( 'HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable' );
            header( "Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size" );
            exit;
        }
        $start = $c_start;
        $end = $c_end;
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
        fseek( $fp, $start );
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content' );
    }

    header( "Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size" );
    header( "Content-Length: " . $length );
    ob_end_flush();


    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while ( ! feof( $fp ) && ClientConnected() && ( $p = ftell( $fp ) ) <= $end )
    {
        $response = stream_get_line( $fp, $buffer );
        echo $response;

    }

    fclose( $fp );
}

function ClientConnected()
{
    if ( connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL || connection_aborted() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


function shutdown()
{
    //main cause of problems is that line
    //posix_kill( getmypid(), 9 );
}
```

You will notice that the above script **has support of Accept ranges so a user can seek into the movie**! **That feature works perfectly as well as the movie itself**. I can see the movie from my player by accessing that file without any problems at all.

### THE PROBLEM

The problem is in the shutdown function. You may ask why i want to use posix_kill and kill the php pid.

User has the option to select multiple movies to see from my application. A user has LIMIT to connections that can be opened to my server. That means if a user has 1 available slots to connect to the server he will be able to open only one movie at once.

For that reason, let's say that a user is currently watching a Movie and he wants to ZAP (change) the current movie to another one.

He won't be able to do that, because the old connection will not be ended fast and the pid will remain open for some seconds more.

### POSIX_KILL Explanation

**If we uncomment the //posix_kill line** of the above code the user **won't be able to see any movie** at all because somehow the posix_kill function override all the above headers and the nginx/php does not send the headers i have in the file.

**However, if i DISABLE the HTTP SEEK and enable the posix_kill as explained, user will be able to watch movies BUT he wont be able to seek** . This is happening because when we have the Accept-Ranges header, players are doing multiple requests to the movie before opening it.

So for example, a player will do 2-3 requests to that PHP File to understand and identify the seek. Posix_kill however will kill those pids fast, and the player wont be able to take the right headers.

### What we want

So, we want a solution that will make the PID of the connection in the server to be dropped instantly when the user closes the connection but remain the seek support.

*PS. The above code with posix_kill enabled works PERFECTLY on live streaming as we don't have seek so a player will only make one request.*

Hope you understand me
Thank you

Comment: What you're dealing with sounds like a perfect job for Mongrel2 and  PHP over ZeroMQ. If you ever get the chance to look at the mentioned, I can assure you that you'll wonder how come you never used it before. Anyway, since you sorted out the problem - consider my comment as something to satisfy the curiosity when you get the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any security issue. Than use mp4 module of nginx. It working you as pseudo streaming for mp4. After this you don't need php to seek movie on any part. Nginx handel itself.

Comment: no the connection must pass from the php file. It's because i do authentication which i didn't include in the above code

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with [**fastcgi_finish_request();**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)

From PHP Manual:

> This function flushes all response data to the client and finishes the
>   request. This allows for time consuming tasks to be performed without
>   leaving the connection to the client open.

My shutdown function became like this:

```
function shutdown()
{
    fastcgi_finish_request();
    posix_kill( getmypid(), 9 );
}
```