# how to get $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'] available at php side for Nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I saw several links where guys some way made available  $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'] at php side.

For example this link:
[NGINX - PHP-FPM Serving Movies Seek & Connection Handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382442/nginx-php-fpm-serving-movies-seek-connection-handle/33197348#33197348)

It sounds like fastcgi consumes Range header. See this link:
https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,247932,247936#REPLY

Maybe I skipped something? How I can resolve this problem?

My current config is:

- nginx 1.8
- php5-fpm 5.5.9
- yii2 based application

Answer (score 0):

My original problem was to organize secured access to the video files hosted on our servers. I recently used apache and all logic related to supporting HTTP RANGE was done at php side. When we migrated to the nginx, this logic become broken, because FAST CGI cache uses own logic related to the ranges. That is why there is no way to have HTTP_RANGE at php level. so I asked the question here.

I have resolved the problem by using [X-Accel-Redirect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) nginx header.
This feature allows to do internal redirects. So php part still can do security validation, but nginx does all other work himself. It supports ranges and caching and partial content. Cool stuff.

I hope this post will save a lot of your time. Thanks